# EF: Integer auto increment primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Previously I have been working only with MySQL databases, it was quite a standard to use auto increment integer settings for the `id` fields.

Trying Entity Framework with `SQLite` database, I have noticed that EF is using a `Guid` structure identifiers by default and therefore requires `string` for such fields. In the result, we have a identifier looking like that:

`a75d9d3d-6543-44fe-9fb8-f19f411503e5`

```
public class AccountDataModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The unique Id
    /// </summary>
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [...]
}
```

Two questions:

- Why is that? Is there any particular reason NOT to use the integer identifiers? Is one better than the other?
- Does EF allow to use integer idenfitiers? If so, how to enable that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change

```
public string Id { get; set; }
```

to

```
public int Id { get; set; }
```

and should change your Identity column type int with seed as 1. Use EF migrations to see the code generated for creating tables, keys and relationships.

Answer (score 1):

If you want Id to be int then you should use type *int* and not *string*.

```
public int Id { get; set; }
```

And for Guid you would use type *Guid*.
Type *string* is rarely used for Id column.